I keep getting a metadata not found error when trying to install geemmap
I am pretty new to python and am using geemap for a project. I tried doing this command: pip install geemap
However, I keep getting the error below:
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [11 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fms64_bl\matplotlib_05359f411a1a48a6870271952064ee1f C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fms64_bl\matplotlib_05359f411a1a48a6870271952064ee1f\.mesonpy-tl69drhd -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fms64_bl\matplotlib_05359f411a1a48a6870271952064ee1f\.mesonpy-tl69drhd\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.5.0
      Source dir: C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fms64_bl\matplotlib_05359f411a1a48a6870271952064ee1f
      Build dir: C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fms64_bl\matplotlib_05359f411a1a48a6870271952064ee1f\.mesonpy-tl69drhd
      Build type: native build
      Program python3 found: YES (C:\Users\sam\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims\python3.BAT)

      ..\meson.build:4:11: ERROR: Command `C:\Users\sam\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims\python3.BAT -m setuptools_scm` failed with status 1.

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fms64_bl\matplotlib_05359f411a1a48a6870271952064ee1f\.mesonpy-tl69drhd\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I tried installing in a virtual environment, this command (pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel), pip cache purge, pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall setuptools, upgrading, pip install numpy pandas ipywidgets earthengine-api folium
I also tried installing specific versions of the dependencies.
I am using a windows computer and doing this in command prompt. Any help is appreciated. I also looked at the other questions similar but none were specific to geemap so I came here.

You forgot to mention your python version
